# Variadic function wrapper for any return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a variadic template wrapper for any function to be passed to it, and (possibly) it's return value to be returned.

For now I've came up with code below, but I really hate that I need 6 different function overloads, 3 for void return types & 3 for non-void return types.

```cpp
// Void return type
// Template for non-member functions
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value == false>
call(Callable worker, Args... params)
{
    worker(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

// Template for member functions (general)
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value>
call(Callable worker, Args... params)
{
    call(std::forward<Callable>(worker), std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

// Template for member functions (object instance extractor)
template <typename Callable, typename Object, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value>
call(Callable worker, Object object, Args... params)
{
    auto fn = std::mem_fn(worker);
    fn(std::forward<Object>(object), std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

// Non-void return types
// Template for non-member functions
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value == false
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value == false
    , std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >
call(Callable worker, Args... params)
{
    return worker(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

// Template for member functions (general)
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value == false
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value
    , std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >
call(Callable worker, Args... params)
{
    return call(std::forward<Callable>(worker), std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}

// Template for member functions (object instance extractor)
template <typename Callable, typename Object, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >::value == false
    && std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value
    , std::result_of_t<Callable(Args...)> >
call(Callable worker, Object object, Args... params)
{
    auto fn = std::mem_fn(worker);
    return fn(std::forward<Object>(object), std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
```

It there any way to possibly get rid of some of these overloads? This approach proves to be working just fine, but code-wise I really would like something a little bit shorter.

Comment: Are you limited to C++14?  C++17 offers [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which does just this.

Comment: Also, it is legal to do `return void_returning_function();` in a function that returns `void` so you really don't need special cases for void functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver, unfortunately for now I'm limited to C++14, so `std::invoke` is a no-go. That was my very first though.
As it goes for `return void_returning_function();`, i did not remembered that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter version with SFINAE (which could replace with `decltype(auto)` if you don't need it).

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args, typename U,
          typename... Params>
auto call(R (T::*arg)(Args...), U &&first, Params &&... params)
    -> decltype((std::forward<T>(first).*
                 arg)(std::forward<Params>(params)...)) {
  return (std::forward<T>(first).*arg)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
auto call(F &&f, Ts &&... args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: This looks nice, but when I'm trying to use it as this, I get compilation errors:
`class Foo { int bar(int, int*); } foo;
int *i = new int;
call(&Foo::bar, foo, 1, a);`
Basically, I receive error: `no matching function for call to 'forward(Foo*&)'
   -> decltype((std::forward<T>(first).*arg)(std::forward<Params>(params)...))`
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Theoden91 It works for me if you change `i` to `a` and use `struct` (since `bar` is private).

Comment: You're right. I found the bug in the code. Thank you very much for help!